# compose - how to create a PostgreSQL user with superuser or replication roles?

Tags: postgresql, compose-db

I'm trying to use compose transporter to replicate changes from postgres to rabbitmq:

```
var source = postgres({
  "uri": "postgres://admin:****@****.dblayer.com:17596/compose"
  "debug": true,
  "tail": true,
  "replication_slot": "slot"
})
var sink = rmq = rabbitmq({
  "uri": "amqps://transporter:****@****.composedb.com:17597/****",
  "routing_key": "test",
  "key_in_field": false
  // "delivery_mode": 1, // non-persistent (1) or persistent (2)
  // "api_port": 15672,
  // "ssl": false,
  // "cacerts": ["/path/to/cert.pem"]
})
t.Source(source).Save(sink)
```

The error:

```
INFO[0001] Listening for changes...                      db=compose logical_decoding_slot=slot
ERRO[0002] error plucking from logical decoding pq: must be superuser or replication role to use replication slots  db=compose
```

How can I setup the Postgres user with superuser or replication roles?  This appears to be disallowed on compose?

```
ALTER USER admin WITH REPLICATION;
```

Results in:

```
ERROR: must be superuser to alter replication users
```

Also note:

> **Can I create a 'superuser'?**
>
> PostgreSQL allows the creation of a superuser. Being a superuser implies the ability to bypass all access
>   permission checks within the database, so superuserdom should not be
>   granted lightly. For security purposes, we do not allow the creation
>   of superusers.
>
> *Source: https://help.compose.com/v2.0/docs/postgresql-faq*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response I received from Compose Support is that superuser accounts are not supported on Compose PostgreSQL.